# Methods that work for both mutable and immutable objects in D

Tags: immutability, d

I'm trying to write an access method for a class in D that I want to work for both mutable and immutable instances.

```
public immutable(double[]) getInputs(uint i)immutable{
  return this.data[i];
}
public double[] getInputs(uint i){
  return this.data[i];
}
```

I keep getting compiler errors unless I make both these versions that do (almost) the exact same thing.

Since I'm not changing any state, is there any way to use a single method that operates both on mutable and immutable instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D has `inout` for this:

```
public inout(double[]) getInputs(uint i) inout
{
    return this.data[i];
}
```

This will work when the object (`this`) is `const`, `immutable`, or neither (mutable). The constness of the returned value will be the same as `this`.

See [the documentation for inout functions](http://dlang.org/function.html#inout-functions) for more information.